# How can i send request to API from Postman?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am going to make request from postman to https://lms.freedomhighschool.ca/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/

but after request i got message
{ Errors: [ {Message: "Forbidden"} ] }

I have Application ID and Application Key but don't understand how to use this data in my request

Comment: can you tell more about the application id and application key

Comment: if you want to pass api key in URL or in header ?

Comment: application id and application key were provided by my client. I think, he recived this credentials from support team.
I tried to pass this credentials via params and heders. But i'm not sure wich keys to use

Comment: Once Confirm with your client what keys to use ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Tool:***
Postman (recommended for OAuth 2.0 Apps)

***Notes:***
Postman is a market-leading API test tool. It is available for free download at [www.getpostman.com](http://www.getpostman.com). You can find Sample Postman Environments and Collections on the Brightspace Github organization. You can find information on how to connect Postman to Brightspace in the Brightspace Developer Community.

***Tool:***
API Test Tool (ID Key Apps Only)

***Notes:***
The API Test Tool runs in a web browser and provides an interface to point to an instance of Brightspace, supply an App ID/Key pair, and log in with a given user account. Once authenticated, you can make calls using a straightforward interface. You can find more information about using the API test tool on the Brightspace Developer Community.

**Conclusion use this -> [API Test Tool](https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/index.php) if you have `Application ID` and `Application Key`**
[image]

[refer this documentation for brief info](https://community.brightspace.com/s/article/The-API-Test-Tool-A-Developers-Secret-Weapon)

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask one more question. 
How can i get user and password for this website ? https://devcop.brightspace.com/d2l/login?sessionExpired=1&target=%2fd2l%2fauth%2fapi%2ftoken%3fx_a%3dMYUQeCQRlhyX07h430JoLw%26x_b%3dCwj2vr0Gr2s39Eyn3DE7cSeVygCcEG3HvQDNz9Jn0Oo%26x_target%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fapitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com%252Findex.php

My client is not technical person. He gave me just application id and key.

Maybe, you could give me suggestion where he can get this user name and password

Comment: See [Paul Janzen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65829574/608191) elsewhere in this question for how to get access to the devcop back-end service.

Answer (score 1):

I highly and strongly recommend you consider switching from D2L's proprietary ID/KEY AUTH over to the Brightspace API OAuth2.

D2L has many resources available on its [Brightspace Developer Community](https://community.brightspace.com/s/group/0F9610000001mZ1CAI/developers). And, even more helpful, is this GitHub repo --> https://github.com/Brightspace/Postman-Collections

In order to get access to DevCop.brightspace.com, you have to be a registered member of the Brightspace Developer Community.

Answer (score 0):

To pass API key-value pair in header -> `x-api-key`
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately i got { Errors: [ {Message: "Forbidden"} ] }